# Terrence Tao Real Analysis exercise: Prove that all Cauchy sequences $(a_n)$ are bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling for one and a half hours trying to think of a proof for this Lemma, I haven't made any progress at all.

It's in Terrence Tao's lectures notes for his Real Analysis course (week 2, lemma 9).

"Prove that all Cauchy sequences $(a_n)$ are bounded".

If any could give me a hint that would be really helpful, thanks.In particular, something I am having an issue with is that most proofs I have seen involve the Max function which hasn't been defined by Tao yet.This makes me think it's not the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(a_n)$ is cauchy, there exists some $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $d(a_n,a_m)<\epsilon$ for all $m \geq n$, in which case $a_m \leq a_n \pm \epsilon$ for all $m \geq n$. So, either the the sequence is bounded by the maximum/minimum of the first $n$ elements of the sequence, or it is bounded by $a_n \pm \epsilon$